# I want to know the name of technique used to create the icon

Tags: icon, android

I have created app named i am poor for learning purpose 
I was trying to create icon the background colour of icon i chosen same as whatsapp icon colour but now I'm seeing difference WhatsApp had applied lighting very properly my problem is that i can see difference but difficult to understand the difference what is that is it gradients or something else? 
How we can achieve this effect? 
[image: screenshot]

EDIT :

Thanks for the answer @sabineR this how my icon look like now[image]

Comment: Yep, looks like a gradient to me.

Comment: How can we achieve this type of gradient in illustrator or photoshop?

Comment: @DrxSalimAnsari - both applications have a gradient tool.

Comment: I know both have gradient tool but see the WhatsApp icon its has only one colour and colours are balanced all corner

Comment: @DrxSalimAnsari - no, the whatsapp icon has a gradient of two distinct colours. You can use the eydropper to sample the colours, add them as swatches, and make a similar gradient using the gradient tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a simple gradient of two colors. I replicated it in photoshop by using the *eye dropper* tool to get the top and bottom color (put them as *foreground* and *background colors*) and then used the *gradient tool* as a straight vertical line from the very top of the icon to the very bottom.

Although I would recommend to not use the exact same colors as a big company that could sue you for copyright infrigement... Or at least first look up the legal stuff about that.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer and advise madam this personal project just for learning android app development i will never upload it on play store i wonder big company have copyright to the colours too which is freely available in nature 

Comment: Well the colors it self shouldn't but the combination of them in a similar environment might. But I think it's still possible to licence colors in a way. For exhample I heard that one newspaper website licenced the link color they used. I'm not sure how the rights work, though.